# Screen doesn't resume after putting on sleep mode after installing NVidia drivers, how to fix it?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, suspend

I am using an

- Asus K510Q
- i5 8th gen
- NVidia 940mx
- 8GB of RAM

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on it.
Whenever I install the NVidia drivers, the OS starts behaving in a weird fashion: the screen doesn't resume after I put the machine on sleep mode. I tried Ubuntu 16.04 also, but I faced the same problem.

I have reinstalled the OS twice because of facing this issue.
Can someone help me with what should I do in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody from the nvidia forums found a solution to this issue:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044633/driver-does-not-wake-gpu-properly-after-suspend-ubuntu-18-10-with-branch-390-410-and-415-/

The user mentions that for him it only works with lightdm, but I use gdm3 and it works fine.
I will paste here the fix (a grub configuration):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
## GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

Only the last two lines are important.

To change the grub configuration edit:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

And then updated the grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

My config:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
4.20.3-042003-generic
Driver Version: 415.27
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. thank you.

Comment: Why are there several nouveau flags in there? I assume those are just leftover from earlier experimentation. I wish this was condensed into what's actually needed for the proprietary driver, not just throwing a bunch of flags at the problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Kernel 5.3.0-61-generic

Answer (score 1):

The only essential change you have to make is to edit the grub settings (`/etc/default/grub`) and add `acpi_osi=Linux` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line.

then update the grub by running the `update-grub` command with superuser access and finally reboot the device. it works on my T440p with Nvidia dGPU as a primary device. (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 5.8.0-48-generic)

be aware that if you add this kernel config to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` it will **NOT** work on a recovery boot situation!