# Black screen after wake up and wrong resolution with the fix

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, nouveau

I'm trying to fix the Nouveau driver bug. When I wake up my computer from sleep, the screen remain black, no image. So I added the `nouveau.modeset=0` in the grub file and after a reboot, the screen resolution is on 800x600. And there is no other options available in the config menu.

I also tried to install the last nVidia driver from the PPA but the computer become extremly laggy after a reboot. I have a nVidia 980M with Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I fix the nouveau bug while the usual fix creates other bugs?

Comment: do you have bumblebee installed? ```sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia```

Comment: I thought that the [bumblebee project was abandonned](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/947#issuecomment-371192713).

Comment: yes, but it is worth I try. I used it some time ago on 16.04 LTS and it solved issues I had with black screens and hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrestling around with this for the past two days. I've found that if you have performed a `apt upgrade` anytime since you first installed ubuntu, then the nvidia drivers will not work. As they are compiled for a specific kernal using a specific gcc version.

If you were to either drop back to the default linux kernal that came with your ubuntu image. (In your case Linux kernel 4.15). Or install the nvidia drivers first after a clean install without performing an upgrade, your issue will be fixed. (Please still remember to `update`).

I have found that using the [lambda stack](https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software) installer will automatically find the right nvidia driver to download and install and will automatically configure CUDA correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted an answer here:

[Screen doesn't resume after putting on sleep mode after installing NVidia drivers, how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093818/screen-doesnt-resume-after-putting-on-sleep-mode-after-installing-nvidia-driver/1113116#1113116)

Try this grub configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

Update grub and reboot.
Works with kernel 4.20.3 (probably works with 4.17+ too) and driver 415.27 from ppa:graphics-drivers.